# How to build a C library with an interface of few functions and the rest of the objects hidden?

Tags: gcc, mingw, symbols, name-clash

Let's suppose I have three C object files: p.o, q.o, r.o, and I want to make a library with them. The first object file, p.o, has a couple of functions I want to export, which are implemented using the other two objects (q.o, r.o). Now I want that, when linking with such library, only the functions in p.o should be seen and none of the others, because their symbols may clash with other objects in the main project. For example, q.o may have some function f() that p.o needs, but that may clash with some f() implemented in the main project that links, among other libraries, with this library. How can I do that using gcc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCC`s [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) feature to hide symbols that are not supposed to be exported. Alternatively, re-factor your library source code in such a way that functions are declared as static and so are not exported beyond the translation unit.

Comment: Visibility is not supported on mingw (gcc 4.4.0).

Comment: On the other hand, naturally "static" is not an option, as the main object of the library must be able to link against the other "hidden" objects and use their functions.

Comment: @user788041: You are right. The only way to use "static" (that I am aware of) is to compile everything into a single translation unit. I think Linux kernel modules are compiled that way.

Comment: Well, if you have access to source code - give your functions more unique name so that they don't clash...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set visibility for your functions: [Controlling Symbol Visibility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html)

Comment: By the way, Apple's GCC is slightly patched, and now is slightly outdated. I'd rather provide a reference to official GCC page, for example.

Comment: Visibility is not supported on mingw (gcc 4.4.0)